# Call previously saved function VBA

Tags: vba, excel

was wondering why I received an error "Compile Error- Argument Not Optional" When I run the following code? I'm a beginner at VBA. Basically, I want it to embed the previously defined function by calling it.

```
 Function testranges(range1 As Range, range2 As Range)
    'function to compare if the values of two ranges are the same
    'define the variables
    Dim range1rows, range1cols, range2rows, range2cols, i, j As Integer
    ' count the rows and columns in each of the ranges
    range1rows = range1.Rows.Count
    range1cols = range1.Columns.Count
    range2rows = range2.Rows.Count
    range2cols = range2.Columns.Count

    'are the ranges the same dimension?
    testranges = (range1rows = range2rows And range1cols = range2cols)

    'if same dimension loop through the cells
    If (testranges) Then

        For i = 1 To range1rows
            For j = 1 To range1cols

            If (range1.Cells(i, j).Value <> range2.Cells(i, j).Value) Then
                testranges = False
            End If

            Next
        Next

    End If

    'loop through
    'for
End Function

'Call previously defined fucntion
Sub comparesheetnew()
    Call testranges

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't skip the range parameters here: `If (testranges) Then` I suggest you use a separate boolean variable for testing inside the procedure.

Comment: @Rory Sorry, I don't quite understand. Mind elaborating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass two ranges to the function whenever you call it. You don't really want to call it recursively inside the function itself so you should use a separate variable - here's a simple fix:

```
Function testranges(range1 As Range, range2 As Range)
'function to compare if the values of two ranges are the same
'define the variables
    Dim range1rows            As Long
    Dim range1cols            As Long
    Dim range2rows            As Long
    Dim range2cols            As Long
    Dim i                     As Long
    Dim j                     As Long
    Dim bMatches              As Boolean

    ' count the rows and columns in each of the ranges
    range1rows = range1.Rows.Count
    range1cols = range1.Columns.Count
    range2rows = range2.Rows.Count
    range2cols = range2.Columns.Count

    'are the ranges the same dimension?
    bMatches = (range1rows = range2rows And range1cols = range2cols)

    ' true if the same size, false otherwise
    testranges = bMatches

    'if same dimensions loop through the cells
    If bMatches Then

        For i = 1 To range1rows
            For j = 1 To range1cols

                If (range1.Cells(i, j).Value <> range2.Cells(i, j).Value) Then
                    testranges = False
                    ' no point testing the rest
                    Exit Function
                End If

            Next
        Next

    End If

End Function

'Call previously defined fucntion
Sub comparesheetnew()
    ' you have to pass two ranges here.
    MsgBox testranges(Range("A1:A10"), Range("B1:B10"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, how am I able to change the two ranges to perform the function on sheet1 and sheet2? I've changed it to  MsgBox testranges(Range("Sheet1"), Range("Sheet2")) but it's wrong

Comment: You need to pass a range to compare, not a worksheet. So it would be like: `MsgBox testranges(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10"), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C10"))` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call a function without passing the parameters to it. (unless they are optional). Defined like below

```
 Function testranges(range1 As Range, range2 As Range)
```

You would have to call the function with passing two ranges to the function e.g

```
Call testranges range("A1:A2"), range("B1:B2")
```

The function itself would not run correctly without two ranges being passed to it

Comment: I've tried amending it to Call testranges("Sheet1, Sheet2") to compare two sheets but I'm given a mismatch error

Comment: Right 2 things. 1) you can not call sheets like that use Call testranges "Sheet1", "Sheet2". 2) your function will not take sheets currently, range1 is defined as a Range so is expecting you to pass it a range. If you wanted sheets to be considered you would have to add these variables to your augement list and then change the code to actually take into account different sheets. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the range1 and range2 parameters to the **testranges** function in the **comparesheetnew** sub.

Comment: I wish to change my code to change the range1 and range2 parameters to a separate paremeter. Is this possible?